# How to improve eXSLT performance problems when using functions

Tags: python, xml, xslt, saxon

### TL;DR:

It seems than running eXSLT is waay slower than its counterpart in XSLT2. (7 minutes vs 18 hours)

Below I explain my problem, writing down both implementations of the same transform, in eXSLT and XSLT2.

Of course, engines are different, as for XSLT2 i use SaxonHE, and for eXSLT I use python with lxml.

And finally I ask for help to improve speed in the eXSLT part, as I would prefer to use python than Java.

---

I have to convert a large (~200k tier 1 elements) XML to csv.

I've got 2 implementations:

- One uses python, so libxml underneath, and I use eXSL.
- Another uses SaxonHE, so I use a XSL2 tranformation for it.

Since when writing a CSV, you have to print the separators even if there is no value for an element, Ive taken this approach:

I've created 2 functions:

`myf:printElement` that receives an Element and a number that represents the number of separators that must be written if the element is empty.

`myf:printAttr` that receives an Attribute, and prints it plus the separator.

If I also defined the separator as:

```
<xsl:param name="delim" select="','"/>
```

The functions are declared in each file as follows:

**XSLT2**

```
<!-- Shortcut function to print an attribute plus a delimiter -->
<xsl:function name="myf:printAttr" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="pAttr" as="attribute()*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($pAttr,$delim)"/>
</xsl:function>

<!-- This function will call the apply templates if the given elements exist. Else, it will return as many delimiters as the number given as second parameter -->
<xsl:function name="myf:printElement" as="item()*">
    <xsl:param name="pElement" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="pCount" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pElement">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$pElement"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- explicit void separator or will add an space -->
            <xsl:value-of select="for $i in 1 to $pCount return $delim" separator=""/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

**eXSLT**

```
<!-- Shortcut function to print an attribute plus a delimiter -->
<func:function name="myf:printAttr">
    <xsl:param name="pAttr"/>
    <func:result select="concat($pAttr,$delim)"/>
</func:function>
<!-- This function will call the apply templates if the given elements exist. Else, it will return as many delimiters as the number given as second parameter -->
<func:function name="myf:printElement" as="item()*">
    <xsl:param name="pElement" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="pCount" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pElement">
            <func:result>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$pElement"/>
            </func:result>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- explicit void separator or will add an space -->
            <func:result select="str:padding($pCount,$delim)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</func:function>
```

The rest of the documents are the same.

So, lets say I have an XML like this:

```
<root>
  <Tier1 attr1="A" attr2="B"/>
  <Tier1 attr1="C" attr2="D">
    <Child2 type="1" val="ABC"/>
    <Child2 type="3" val="123"/>
  </Tier1>
  <Tier1 attr1="E" attr2="F">
    <Child2 type="2" val="pancakes"/>
    <Child2 type="1" val="42"/>
    <Child3 a="H">
        <Child4 Month="JUN"/>
    </Child3>
  </Tier1>
</root>
```

With:

```
<xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="root/Tier1"/>`
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Tier1">
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(@attr1)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(@attr2)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(Child2[@type='1']/@val)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(Child2[@type='2']/@val)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(Child2[@type='3']/@val)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <!-- line break after each Tier1 -->
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="$break"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Child3">
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(@a)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="ama:printElement(Child4,3)"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Child4">
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(@Day)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(@Month)"/>
    <!-- We dont want comma after last element-->
    <xsl:value-of select=@Average/>
</xsl:template>
```

I would get the desired csv output:

```
T1_attr1, T1_attr2, C2_t1, C2_t2, C2_t3, C3_a, C4_Mont, C4_Day, C4_Average
A,B,,,,,,,
C,D,ABC,,123,,,,
E,F,42,pancakes,,H,JUN,3,1200
```

Some notes about this above:

- Child2 can be repeated under Tier1, but with only a given set of values for type, and not repeated.
- Also there is no text inside the elements, that makes this approach with the 2 functions cover all the possible cases I can encounter. Although printAttr would probably work with text nodes also.
- Ive added the column names to make it easier to read. In code I add it at start, an inner node set with eXSLT, a simple array of string with XSLT2.

### So, now, the problem:

As I said at start, I have to run the transform to a huge file, with more than 200k Tier1 elements.

- With SaxonHE it takes 7 minutes
- With Python, it takes **18 hours**

Both transform script/program do the same:

1. Open the file
2. Open the XSLT
3. Apply the later to the former
4. Save result

I know that I am talking of different implementations of a transform engine, but this difference is too notable to be because of this.
The only way to test the same engine would be using eXSLT under Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE as it is not available in Saxon-HE.
And, of course, there is no XSLT2 implementation in python.

I would like to know why the python version takes too long. Is this inherent to the use of eXSLT? or **is there a way to improve this?**

Of course this is an example XML, the real one has a lot of more elements and it is really more complex.

This is part of a larger project and I would'nt like to depend on the JVM only for this, but, the difference is so huge that as it is now, Python is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `<func:function name="myf:printElement" as="item()*">` really the code you have? The spec http://exslt.org/func/elements/function/index.html does not show any `as` attribute. Do you get better performance when removing those `as` attributes and using `version="1.0"` in your stylesheet (assuming that currently you have `version="2.0"` as otherwise I don't see why your snippets would work at all)?

Comment: Yup, it works, and ofc version="1.0" for eXSLT, and "2.0" for XSLT2. I will try, anyway, to remove that `as`, that probably was left when I converted from xslt2 to eXSLT. Weird indeed, that I did not get any error.

Comment: Also, It would not work under pythom to run an XSLT2 ...

Comment: Well an XSLT 1.0 processor when presented a `version="2.0"` stylesheet is supposed to try to run that http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#forwards. As for the performance problems, what happens when you use xsltproc/libxslt without Python (from the command line), does it also take that long?

Comment: I also think you could simply code like `<func:function name="myf:printAttr">
    <xsl:param name="pAttr"/>
    <func:result select="concat($pAttr,$delim)"/>
</func:function>` to a template `<xsl:template match="@*"><xsl:value-of select="concat(., $delim)"/></xsl:template>` and use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@attr1"/>` instead of e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="myf:printAttr(@attr1)"/>`. But obviously the right approach would be to profile the Python/libxslt code to see where the time is spent to then try to improve those parts. Otherwise it is hard to tell why it takes that long.

Comment: Good point about the template! I will probably change it. I am profiling now the exslt. Let's see if I find the problem.Thanks!

Comment: @Trompa Please fix your samples. Neither is your sample XML well-formed nor matches it the desired output you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks as if you are massively over-engineering this problem.

The following simple XSLT 1.0 transformation

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:text>T1_attr1,T1_attr2,C2_t1,C2_t2,C2_t3,C3_a,C4_Month,C4_Day,C4_Average</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Tier1" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Tier1">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@attr1" />                   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@attr2" />                   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child2[@type = '1']/@val" /> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child2[@type = '2']/@val" /> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child2[@type = '3']/@val" /> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child3/@a" />                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child3/Child4/@Month" />     <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child3/Child4/@Day" />       <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child3/Child4/@Average" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to

```
<root>
  <Tier1 attr1="A" attr2="B">
  </Tier1>
  <Tier1 attr1="C" attr2="D">
    <Child2 type="1" val="ABC" />
    <Child2 type="3" val="123" />
  </Tier1>
  <Tier1 attr1="E" attr2="F">
    <Child2 type="2" val="pancakes" />
    <Child2 type="1" val="42" />
    <Child3 a="H">
        <Child4 Month="JUN" Day="3" Average="1200" />
    </Child3>
  </Tier1>
</root>
```

produces

```
T1_attr1,T1_attr2,C2_t1,C2_t2,C2_t3,C3_a,C4_Month,C4_Day,C4_Average
A,B,,,,,,,
C,D,ABC,,123,,,,
E,F,42,pancakes,,H,JUN,3,1200
```

Comment: True, I can be a little biased by the DRY principle. I did not like to have so much repeated commas, and having the elements separated in each match seemed good to me. But I dont use to write XSLT and probably applied criteria that dont have much sense in this domain.
Thanks!

Comment: @Trompa This template goes through 20 MB of XML (~200k `<Tier1>` elements, as shown) in a few seconds.

Comment: @Trompa DRY does have sense in XSLT, but sometimes in-lining stuff is the fastest way (and the most readable, I might add). How does it perform in your environment? (Try both Saxon and lxml)

Comment: I am doing a new transform to test it in the original file. and i will post the results
Still It feels weird the difference between Saxon and lxml.

Comment: Well, the two are fundamentally different, you cannot really expect them to show comparable performance characteristics.

Comment: Sure, that was part of the problem, could not find an engine that supported both, that makes sense, if you got xslt2, you dont need eXSLT, but, anyway, 7 mins to 18hours was way larger difference that i could expect

Comment: It's a bit much, that's true. I don't know enough about the internals of lxml to explain it, but your approach was too complicated even for XSLT 2.0, so maybe it's not worth worrying too much about it. (Do you have performance comparison data yet?)

Comment: Ive got more than 100 items, with several depth levels, so it will take a bit. :) Thats why I tried to have it as clean as possible

Comment: Ok, finally got the results. This is on a 166M file:
New XSLT in PYT:  `23.52s user 0.76s system 97% cpu 24.786 total`
New XSLT in JVA:  `78.86s user 0.96s system 407% cpu 19.606 total`
Old XSLT2 in JVA:  `76.88s user 0.78s system 460% cpu 16.853 total`
So, I guess the use of function adds a lot of overhead. Difference now is neglibile. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, you can try and use variables to store elements you need more than once (like the `Child3/Child4` above), this might help squeeze out a few more seconds. Interesting to see that Saxon runs multi-threaded and still is considerably slower than lxml/libxslt.

Comment: Indeed, the initial purpose of using functions was reducing boilerplate code, right now Ive got lines and lines of Child3/Child4/Child5/@Attribute. I will check the variables approach. Thanks again!!!